# Magento: combine bundle and simple product

Tags: magento, bundle

Is there a extension or a way to combine a simple product and a bundle product into a new product?

Comment: No, there is not.  Although may there is — it's not clear what you mean by combining a bundle and a simple product into a new product.  Also also, you might have more luck with this question rephrased on the Magento Stack Exchange — Stack Overflow is strictly for programming, and it sounds like you're looking for a prebuilt solution.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hi do you mean that while viewing simple products you want to display bundle products in promotion? Then you can refer this [Promosets](http://www.shopmages.com/grouped-product-promotions-promosets.html)